# Can you import variables into .bashrc?

Tags: sh, bash

I'm looking at having a separate file (e.g. bash_aliases) to hold variables that represent colour characters e.g:

```
Black="\[\033[0;30m\]"        # Black
```

Putting this in my rc/profile files would make it look horrendous; is there some way I can simply read in these variables from another file?

Comment: Yes, you can put them in another file, like `.colors`, and in your profile, do `. ~/.colors` (assuming `.colors` is in your home directory).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can evaluate external shell script commands in current shell using `source` command, or `.`:

```
source .color_rc
```

or

```
. .color_rc
```

in your `.bashrc`

Comment: Perfect, thanks. What is the difference between this and ./.color_rc?

Comment: @ginister you mean between `.color_rc` and `./.color_rc`? There is no difference: `./` is path relative to current directory, so `./.color_rc` is `.color_rc` in current directory which is same as simply `.color_rc`